# Java GUI JButton to actionlistner

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, joptionpane

I have made a GUI in NetBeans. It's a chat program and i have 4 commandos like /join, /leave, /whisper and /leave

```
private void CommandoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "The following commandos are:" + "\n" + "\n" + "/join Channel name" + "\n" + "/leave channel name" + "\n" + "/whisper nick message" + "\n" + "/quit - quit the program");
    }
```

And this is OK, but i want actionlister instead of the showMessageDialog so i can push on of them and it comes in my JTextField. I think i can get them there but i don't know how to get the actionlistener combined with this.

EDIT: 
What i want is to push the Commando button and get up a windows where i have 4 new buttons, each with one commando (/join, /leave, /whisper and /exit) so when i push 1 of these buttons i get the commando in my text field so i just need to write the rest. 
So if i push the "/join" button, i just need to write the channel name.

EDIT2: If I was pretty bad in describing the problem, I can show what i wanted and have done so far:

```
 private void showCommandActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        Object[] options = { "/join", "/leave", "/whisper", "/quit", "Ingenting" };


        int choice= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, "What do u want to do? ", null, WIDTH, WIDTH, null, options, rootPane);

        switch (choice) {
                case 0:
                    skrivTekst.setText("/Join ");
                skrivTekst.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    skrivTekst.setText("/Leave");
                skrivTekst.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    skrivTekst.setText("/Whisper");
                skrivTekst.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case 3:
                skrivTekst.setText("/Join ");
                skrivTekst.requestFocus();

                case 4:

                    System.exit(1); //this is wrong. i just want to close this window, not the whole program 
                default:

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "donno what!?!?!?!?!?!?!" + choice);
            }


    }
```

I hope this show what i wanted and what i have done. Ty to all :)
So the only problem i have left is closing the one JOptionPane window and not the program

Comment: Your question is not so clear, mind to rephrase?

Comment: If you want to add actionListener to JButton then use `button.addActionListener(actionListener)` method.

Comment: maybe you have look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html, there are http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input,

Answer (score 2):

1) you can implements [JRadioButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) in the [ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html), then only one of choices would be available for selection, there you can implelements `ActionListener`, and inside `ActionListener` `setText()` for `JTextField`

2) please use standard Swing `JComponents` rather than prepared `Components` from the `palette`, sometimes is too hard override basic Swing methods

[image]

simple example based on example for JRadioButton's from tutorial

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

/*
 * RadioButtonDemo.java is a 1.4 application that requires these files:
 * images/Bird.gif images/Cat.gif images/Dog.gif images/Rabbit.gif
 * images/Pig.gif
 */
public class RadioButtonDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static String birdString = "Bird";
    private static String catString = "Cat";
    private static String dogString = "Dog";
    private static String rabbitString = "Rabbit";
    private static String pigString = "Pig";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel picture;

    public RadioButtonDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        //Create the radio buttons.
        JRadioButton birdButton = new JRadioButton(birdString);
        birdButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        birdButton.setActionCommand(birdString);
        birdButton.setSelected(true);
        JRadioButton catButton = new JRadioButton(catString);
        catButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        catButton.setActionCommand(catString);
        JRadioButton dogButton = new JRadioButton(dogString);
        dogButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        dogButton.setActionCommand(dogString);
        JRadioButton rabbitButton = new JRadioButton(rabbitString);
        rabbitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        rabbitButton.setActionCommand(rabbitString);
        JRadioButton pigButton = new JRadioButton(pigString);
        pigButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        pigButton.setActionCommand(pigString);
        //Group the radio buttons.
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(birdButton);
        group.add(catButton);
        group.add(dogButton);
        group.add(rabbitButton);
        group.add(pigButton);
        //Register a listener for the radio buttons.
        birdButton.addActionListener(this);
        catButton.addActionListener(this);
        dogButton.addActionListener(this);
        rabbitButton.addActionListener(this);
        pigButton.addActionListener(this);
        //Set up the picture label.
        picture = new JLabel("Narrative");
        //The preferred size is hard-coded to be the width of the
        //widest image and the height of the tallest image.
        //A real program would compute this.
        //picture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(177, 122));
        //Put the radio buttons in a column in a panel.
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        radioPanel.add(birdButton);
        radioPanel.add(catButton);
        radioPanel.add(dogButton);
        radioPanel.add(rabbitButton);
        radioPanel.add(pigButton);
        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        pigButton.setVisible(false);
        rabbitButton.setVisible(false);
        add(picture, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    /** Listens to the radio buttons.
     * @param e
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String narr = e.getActionCommand();
        picture.setText(narr);
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid.
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = RadioButtonDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioButtonDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new RadioButtonDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want 4 buttons, each one setting a command text into the text field, is that right?

```
joinButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        theTextField.setText("/join");
    }
});
```

And do the same with the other 3 buttons.

This is really basic stuff. Read the [tutorial about event listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

Comment: @down_voter please I hope that you'll send here some description

Comment: Whatever is the answer but the question itself is somewhat incomplete +1 can at least offset the downvote.

Comment: I answered to the question as I understood it. And now that the OP has explained what he wants, it looks like my understanding was the correct one.

Comment: Yes absolutely it's correct one and the tutorial is also worth-mentioning I found.

Comment: TY dude, theTextField.setText("/join"); worked perfectly whit my JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == join) {
        textField.setText("/join");
    } else if (source == leave) {
        textField.setText("/leave");
    } else if (source == whisper) {
        textField.setText("/join");
    } else {
        textField.setText("/exit");
    }
}
```

This is going on the assumption that your buttons are named join, leave, whisper, and exit.